# What is difference between SSL Pinning and Certificate Pinning?

Tags: android, ios, security, mobile

Explain the difference between `SSL Pinning` and `Certificate Pinning` and how things work in both? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

SSL Pinning is a security layer to prevent the MITM attacks. Certificate pinning is a type of SSL pinning. You can either pin the whole certificate or you can user another pinning type called public key pinning. If you use public key pinning, you/the company you work for will have the ability to extend the certificate with the same public key. Here is a [medium link](https://medium.com/@appmattus/android-security-ssl-pinning-1db8acb6621e) for detailed info.